# Prevent custom textbox from adding blockquotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day. I`m creating a fully custom comments box with custom textbox for new comments.

```
 <div type="text" class="leavecomment" placeholder="  what you think?" contenteditable="true" role="textbox"></div>
```

Crafting the REPLY feature put me into trouble: my custom div textbox acts super wrong after appending "blockquote" inside it.

```
quote = $.parseHTML("<blockquote><a>"+ user + "</a>" + quote + "</blockquote> <br>");
        $(".leavecomment").append(quote);
```

The caret stuck inside the blockquote and, if user tries to move caret on next line, it creates a new blockquote. Here is the link below showing the problem. Is there any workout from this trouble?

https://jsfiddle.net/u6Lhoj8a/10/
P.S. Also if anybody knows the source, where there is an example of text input like stackoverflow have, with additional features, it will be really great if you share it. thx.

update: The temporary decision comes as appending br separately. It moves caret on next string automaticly.

```
$(".leavecomment").focus();
        $(".leavecomment").append(quote);
        $(".leavecomment").append("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the contendeditable attribute along with the role attribute to the 'blockquote' tag.
The HTML would look like this:

```
  <div class="comment-content">
    <div type="text" class="leavecomment" placeholder="  А что вы думаете по этому поводу?">
      <blockquote contenteditable="true" role="textbox"><a>User</a>quote</blockquote>
    </div>
    <button class="submitcomment">Submit</button>
  </div>
```